# How do we have the definition of hyperbolic functions and trigonometric functions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I knew hyperbolic functions and trig functions for a long time, but I often forget the definition of it. So I think I need some tricks or intuition to remember them.

$$sh \, x = \frac{e^x - e ^{-x}}{2}$$ and
$$ sin \, x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just remember Euler's formula for circular trigonometric functions:

$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$$
$$e^{-ix} = \cos -x + i\sin -x = \cos x - i\sin x$$

Then isolate $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. For the hyperbolic, remember the relationship:

$$e^x = \cosh x + \sinh x$$
$$e^{-x} = \cosh -x + \sinh -x = \cosh x - \sinh x$$

Then isolate respectively.